# Hyperlink to range of cells with same name/value - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I have a Spreadsheet with a DASHBOARD + multiple (300+) sheets (within the same spreadsheet). Within the DASHBOARD I have a range column with the names of all sheets.

I'd like to automatically hyperlink all cells to sheet with corresponding name.

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THUPo.png)

Comment: It is unclear _why_ you want to insert hyperlinks in the dashboard. Is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)?

Comment: Sorry, a bit indistinct from me there. I'd like to insert hyperlinks to easily jump to corresponding sheet. The sheets are being used by different resources - so with a link they wont have to scroll through the enire sheet-list to find correct sheet.

Comment: You will find that the name box is much easier to use.

Comment: Nope, It is way easier to click once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function convertToLinks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("DASHBOARD");
  var range = sh.getRange("A11:A15");
  var data = range.getValues();
  var formulaArr = [];
  data.forEach(sheet => {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet[0]);
    if(targetSheet){
      var url = ss.getUrl() + '#gid=' + targetSheet.getSheetId(); 
      formulaArr.push(['=HYPERLINK("'+ url +'","'+ sheet[0] +'")'])
    }else{
      formulaArr.push([sheet[0]]);
    }
  })
  range.setValues(formulaArr);
}
```

This script above will convert cells **A11:A15** to hyperlinks of the corresponding sheets.

**Example:**

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

### References:

- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Sheet.getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid)
- [Spreadsheet.getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I'm after, and I'll try to implement it as soon as a new DASHBOARD is ready to go (had to nuke the last one due to some other issues). I'll update you, and accept this as solution as soon as I give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need hyperlinks to quickly jump to another sheet. Instead, use the name box. It is located in the formula bar to the left of the ƒ symbol.

Click the name box and type part of a sheet name to quickly locate that sheet, then press **Enter** to go to the sheet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is a step towards what I want. Tho would I like to link the cells to corresponding sheet - so that the resources using the Spreadsheet can look at the DASHBOARD to see what "job" (A, B, C...) needs attention, and easily one-click to the correct job (sheet)

Comment: That is a different question. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a different question regarding your reporting issue.

Comment: It is only one question in the post, and it is now solved. Anyway, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script, but also add search for the cell you need to go to (this can be done by a formula in column C) or filter based on some more info ...

```
function onEdit(event){
  var sh = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var cel = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if (sh.getName()=='DASHBOARD' && cel.getColumn()==2 && cel.getRow()>1 && cel.getValue()){
    try {
      cel.setValue(!cel.getValue())
      // add the right destination in the targeted sheet ...
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(cel.offset(0,-1).getValue()).activate()
    }
    catch(err){

    }
  }
}
```

[image]